How to ask for the answer "I'm the third year of PhD"?
If I desire a answer "I'm in the third year of PhD" from someone with both the year and degree in it, how could I ask with just one sentence?

Why "in one sentence"?  Are you having a conversation with someone that you are meeting for the first time? Use two sentences. . . In fact use 10 or 20 sentences, since there are lots of other things to talk about.  Also a PhD doesn't have a "major".  (but I suppose you mean the area of research)

Sorry I actually mean degree. I used a wrong word.

Thanks for your tips.

Under what circumstances would you do this? Is this some sort of "everyone introduce themselves" exercise, or a one-to-one conversation? Why do you need that particular form of response? Why does the prompt have to be a single sentence?

Cause in China, If someone ask you "what year are you in"? People may answer like this "研一“, which means "the first year of master's".

So, are you specifically thinking of a situation in which you are speaking to a person at a Chinese University?   Because if you are thinking of a situation in which you are talking to someone from another country, you will need to adapt to their education system (the UK and the USA have very very different systems)

This: I'm in the third year of PhD. is not a question which is what you said. The question can be: When did you finish your PhD?

Imagine the following conversation:

-- What do you do?
-- I'm a student.
-- What year are you in?

The reply would probably contain the information you need.  The UK has 3 year undergraduate degrees, and an undergrad would reply "I'm in my first/second/third (or last) year.  The US college system has 4 year degrees, and special names are often used: "freshman, sophomore, junior, senior".
Postgraduates might only specify their degree. In the UK, Masters degrees are typically one year (full time) so there'd be no need to mention a "year".  In the US, Masters are often two years. So an American might well respond "I'm in the first/second (or last) year of my Masters".  Doctoral degrees often have no set length, so a PhD student is less likely to specify a "year". But "I'm in the second year of a PhD" would be a reasonable response.
So "What year are you in?" would probably be enough.  But conversations are not "launch and leave" you can always ask a supplementary or follow up question:

-- What year are you in?
-- Second year.
-- As an undergraduate?
-- No, PhD, in marine biology. I study whales.


I don't know of any one-sentence question that would likely result in that response. Well, other than linking two questions with "and" or some such.
A likely conversation would go like this:
Al: What degree program are you in?
Bob: I'm studying for a PhD.
Al: Oh, really? And what year are you in?
Bob: I'm in my third year.
You could mash the two questions together and ask, "What degree program are you in, and what year of that program?" I suppose that's technically one sentence but it's still two questions.
Side note: At the school I went to, and also at the school where my ex-wife got her masters, a PhD program was 2 years, so the only way to be in the 3rd year of your PhD was if you failed enough classes that you didn't complete on schedule. Typically a Bachelor's takes 4 years, than a Masters takes 2 more years, then a PhD takes yet another 2 years. But I don't claim to have broad knowledge of every school in the country so maybe this doesn't apply generally.

I think you will find that the length of degree courses varies from country to country and even university. In the UK they are typically (but not necessarily always) 3 years for a Bachelor's, 1 year for a Masters and 3 for a PhD. Some, particularly Masters, can be taken part time and spread over more years.

@PeterJennings Oh, yes, I meant to say that it might well be different in other countries and maybe other universities. Interesting point about part time. When I was in college, they technically determined your "year" by how many credits you had completed, not how many years you had been attending. So you could attend for 2 years and be a third-year student or vice versa, depending on your course load. But I wonder how many people who have been studying part time for, say, 4 years would say "I am a 2nd year student".

In a back-and-forth conversation, linking the two questions with "and" would come across as a slightly rude, since it's asking for a bit "too much" information at once.  Mind you, this is less of a problem if it's socially clear that the information will be reciprocated (i.e., either during a group introductions or if you are asking after first providing the information yourself).
